# Camera controll in Libgdx

Tags: libgdx, box2d, camera

I've a condition in my game where, I want my camera to follow the Player(its a body from Box2d) and in some not.
This is the start screen of my game:

[image: Game begining Screen]

Now, when i press a button(space) the player get an LinearVelocity in x,y direction and starts flying..[image: flying]

As soon as it reaches the end. The box is now out of the camera. 

 
To fix this I made my camera centered the box.[image: player centered]

This is where I screwed. I dont want my ground to come in the center it should always needs to be at bottom.. like in Picture 1 and the player should also needs to be at the left-bottom at the start of the game.  And when player flies away ... the x and y coordinates should be moved as my player moves ... i have certain height where player can fly so camera should be able to move in y-axis also.. and the game is endless running game so x- cordinates also keeps comming in.

Answer (score 2):

When centering the camera using `lookAt` you need to clamp the `y` value to be the max of the body's `y` and the `y` of the ground plus half the viewport height
(possibly adjusting for the height of the ground).

Something like this might make sense;

```
float x = body.getWorldCenter().x;
float y = Math.max(body.getWorldCenter().y, ground.getWorldCenter().y + camera.viewportHeight / 2.0f);

camera.lookAt(x, y, 0.0f);
```

(Note that I might have gottent some the api calls wrong, it's from memory)

Answer (score 1):

I had this class in previous project

```
public class ExtendedCamera extends OrthographicCamera {
    public Player player;

    public ExtendedCamera(Player player) {
        super(Constants.WORLD_WIDTH, Constants.WORLD_HEIGHT);
        this.player = player;
    }

    public void followPlayer() {
        if (player.body.getPosition().x - position.x > Constants.CAMERA_FOLLOW_LINE_X) {
            position.x = player.body.getPosition().x
                    - Constants.CAMERA_FOLLOW_LINE_X;
            update();
        } else if (player.body.getPosition().x - position.x < -Constants.CAMERA_FOLLOW_LINE_X) {
            position.x = player.body.getPosition().x
                    + Constants.CAMERA_FOLLOW_LINE_X;
            update();
        }
        if (player.body.getPosition().y - position.y > Constants.CAMERA_FOLLOW_LINE_Y) {
            position.y = player.body.getPosition().y
                    - Constants.CAMERA_FOLLOW_LINE_Y;
            update();
        } else if (player.body.getPosition().y - position.y < -Constants.CAMERA_FOLLOW_LINE_Y) {
            position.y = player.body.getPosition().y
                    + Constants.CAMERA_FOLLOW_LINE_Y;
            update();
        }
    }
}
```

It's a bit verbose but it works. Just call `camera.followPlayer()` after updating player's position. Basically player has free movement zone and if he moves out this zone, camera follows him. Play with `CAMERA_FOLLOW_LINE` to achieve best result.